# Related post based on 2 categories

Tags: plugins, categories, taxonomy

Lest say i have
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3

Inside a post which is located in category 1, I would like to show list of posts which are in category 2 and 3. If it is only in category 2 or only in category 3 it shouldn't be shown.

I was that there are

[Multiple Taxonomy Handling:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Can it be done this way?

```
    'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category 1',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'category1',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category 2',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'category2',
    ),
),
```

If yes where does this code needs to be implemented in?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below-

```
$query = get_posts( 
        array( 
                'category__and' => array( 
                    6, // Your category-1 ID
                    7 // Your category-2 ID
                    // And so on and so fourth
                ) 
        ) 
);
```

Now in `$query` variable you'll get the object of posts which are in both ***Category 1*** and ***Category 2*** and so on and so fourth.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Hope It will Work.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => array(1,2) );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, though: The code needs to be added to a template file, a functions file, a plugin file, or wherever else the "Loop" (based on WP_Query) is called and modified by arguments ($args).

I'm not sure if the question is applying the WordPress terminology precisely, but, to take it literally - produce a list of posts, collected by categories, within a post - one simple, basic alternative would be to write a shortcode function, which would go in your theme's functions.php

```
/** 
 *  PRODUCE A LIST OF FIVE POSTS 
 *  EACH WITH BOTH OF TWO SPECIFIED CATEGORIES 
**/
add_shortcode( 'last_five_posts_two_cats', 'wpse_list_posts_by_two_cats' );

function wpse_list_posts_by_two_cats() {

    //note "category__and" (like in the_dramatist's code) NOT category
    $args = array( 

         'posts_per_page' => 5, 
         'category__and' => array( 1, 2 ) 

    );

    $output = '<ul>' ;

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {

        $output .= '<li>' ;

        $output .= get_the_title( $post ) ;

        $output .= '</li>' ;

    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output ;

}
```

So, if you then placed the shortcode `[last_five_posts_two_cats]` in your post, it would produce a list of the last five posts that were in both category 1 and 2.

(NOTE: I updated this answer to use "return" instead of "echo," using "echo" being a common mistake of the sort I've made like three times in the last 24 hours, but hope never to make again, since it will often produce unexpected and undesirable results.)